# How can I fix two conflicting SSL certificates? (One expired)

Tags: https, security-certificate, webserver, amazon-aws

### **Background:**

I recently inherited management of a web project and ran into an issue with an expired SSL certificate. The site is hosted on AWS with a wildcard certificate generated from ACM, which is active and working. However, I discovered the issue is a second expired certificate, generated manually by Let's Encrypt, which is causing my issue.

After testing validity of several URLs, I found that:

```
www.mywebsite.example   →   Working AWS certificate
mywebsite.example       →   Expired certificate
```

Which is bizarre, considering my AWS certificate both uses `mywebsite.example` as well as a wildcard `*.mywebsite.example`

### **Question:**

I was under the assumption that if a domain held two certificates, an expired one shouldn't affect a working one, and the wildcard certificate should cover both cases. How can I fix this issue so that the wildcard certificate from AWS will apply to all traffic, instead of just `www.mywebsite.example` URLs?

Comment: "a domain held two certificates" a domain does not hold certificates. On any given server, you can store as many certificates as you like. What matters then is how, in your case, the webserver is configured: which certificate it uses in which cases (it can be one different per virtualhost, or the same for both if all names are in the SAN extension or covered by a single wildcard, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I understand that the domain itself doesn't hold certificates. But I didn't want to say server since I wasn't sure, for example, the AWS certificate is actually located on the EC2 server itself and not in some other location.

That said, does the certificate only get directed to if a configuration has a virtual host pointing to said certificate?